# Write error in Fortran

Tags: fortran, output

I am struggling to read from one input text file into a new text file using the Fortran compiler in Visual Studio 10. My input file is in gslib format (attached)

```
program main  

! Unit numbers:  

      lisa = 4  
      lfke = 9  

! Writing input data to file Lisa  

      open(unit=lisa,file='fake.dat',status='OLD',err=80)  
      open(unit=lfke,file='dlfke',status='NEW', err=80)  
      read(lisa,*,err=80)  
      read(lisa,*,err=80) line  
      write(9,*) line    
      close(unit=lisa)  
      close(unit=lfke)           
      80   stop 'ERROR in test file!'  
      end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for any assistance. I can upload the data file if necessary

Comment: What value has `test`?  Where is label `80`?  What goes wrong for you?  What results do you expect/get?

Comment: Maybe your data is `fake`. But seriously, please add the exact error message, and turn your code above into a [mcve]. This might even include an abridged version of the input file that produces the problem (even in its abridged state).

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the link to the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/45fka7a9qjpv5mk/fake.dat?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

This program is always going to produce the error message "ERROR in test file", whether or not there is an error.  After executing line the close statements, it will next execute line 80 with the stop statement.  You will probably find it easier, as your develop your program, to remove the `err=80` tests in each IO statement.  Then if there is an IO error, the program will automatically terminate and produce a specific message about the program.  These `err=`branches are useful if you want to have your program handle the error, but with this implementation its hiding what the IO error was since all IO errors produce the same message.

Comment: Thank you very much :) The file outputs a single line in the file (the value 4 which refered to the number of columns). My problem is not being able to print the other lines. I did try do loop but it didnt write. I think i may be writing out incorrectly. Thank you once again and i apologise for any silly questions. I am working on someone else's code and am new to programming.